# How to pass multi line string as input parameter for a jbehave story?

Tags: bdd, jbehave

I have a jbehave story for which I am passing a string as data to a parameter.

Example:

```
|line|
|hi.how ade you|
```

It gives error as

`expected hi.how are you`

```
But is : 
hi
how are you
```

So how can I handle this enter in the data... Because if I give `\n` it is considering it as a part of data

Comment: Can you supply some code, what have you tested so far?

Comment: If you were to get the parameter and inside the definition add a line that replaces all matches for "\n" with an actual new line, wouldn't this fix your problem?

You're trying to do multiline text inside a table, and that won't work with most Gherkin based tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A story:

```
Narrative:

As a tester
I want to use a string that spans multiple lines as a parameter
So that I can test scenarios using multiline strings

Scenario: User enters a string that spans multiple lines

When the user enters a string: This
is
a very
long
string

that
spans
multiple
lines

and even
has

some empty
lines


Then I can see this string in the console
```

An implementation of steps:

```
public class MySteps {

    private String myString;

    @When("the user enters a string: $string")
    public void userEntersString(String string){
        myString = string;
    }

    @Then("I can see this string in the console")
    public void printTheStringToTheConsole(){
        System.out.println("====== the string starts here =======");
        System.out.println(myString);
        System.out.println("====== the string endss here =======");
    }
}
```

An outcome:

```
Running story org/buba/jbsimple/stories/my.story

(org/buba/jbsimple/stories/my.story)
Narrative:
As a tester
I want to use a string that spans multiple lines as a parameter
So that I can test scenarios using multiline strings
Scenario: User enters a string that spans multiple lines
When the user enters a string: This
is
a very
long
string

that
spans
multiple
lines

and even
has

some empty
lines
====== the string starts here =======
This
is
a very
long
string

that
spans
multiple
lines

and even
has

some empty
lines
====== the string endss here =======
Then I can see this string in the console



(AfterStories)
```

Comment: Do you know how to stop JBehave from trimming lines of a multi-line parameter?

Comment: @Alissa plase post this as a separate question, not a comment.

Comment: sorry, I thought it would be OK here. Posted separately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269885/how-to-stop-jbehave-from-trimming-multiline-parameters